# How to add new key in json using karate.set()

Tags: karate

Hi i am trying to add new key and value to json using karate.set but its not working getting exception as invalid varibale name, below is my code:

```
Backgroung:
* def myjson = {name: 'test', start_date: '27-04-2017'}
* def localDateTime = Java.type("java.time.LocalDateTime").now()
Scenario:
 * string endDate = 'myjson.end_date'
 * def endDateTmp = karate.eval(endDate)
 * eval if (endDateTmp == null) karate.set(myjson,'$.end_date',localDateTime)
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: if (endDateTmp == null) karate.set(myjson,'$.end_date',localDateTime)
    at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.eval(ScriptBindings.java:115)
    at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.updateBindingsAndEval(ScriptBindings.java:103)
    at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.evalInNashorn(ScriptBindings.java:88)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalJsExpression(Script.java:362)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.eval(StepDefs.java:581)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid variable name: {name:test, start_date:27-04-2017}
at com.intuit.karate.Script.validateVariableName(Script.java:553)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.setValueByPath(Script.java:1480)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.setValueByPath(Script.java:1455)
    at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBridge.set(ScriptBridge.java:101)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$23$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:1)
```

If key already exist then trying to set is working, please suggest me how to add new key using karate.set() or any other way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to read through the Karate documentation and examples a little more carefully and also be clear about some JS concepts.

```
* def myjson = { name: 'test', start_date: '27-04-2017' }
* def localDateTime = Java.type("java.time.LocalDateTime").now()
* if (!myjson.end_date) myjson.end_date = localDateTime + ''
* print myjson
```

Which results in:

```
[print] {
  "name": "test",
  "start_date": "27-04-2017",
  "end_date": "2018-07-05T18:13:07.547"
}
```

Note that I converted the Java Date to a String via concatenation. I leave how to format it correctly the way you want as a homework for you. Refer the example here for some hints: https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-interop